# getWindowHandles in selenium is always returning size as 1 even though multiple instances of chrome are open

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have multiple chrome windows open, but getWindowHandles in selenium is always returning size as 1 even though multiple instances of chrome are open.

here is the code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Downloads/New folder/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.rediffmail.com/");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

    Set<String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(ids.size());     
    System.out.println(ids);
```

and here is the output:

```
1
[CDwindow-DBDAD89956F46A4DE6DC3F16E70D79A6]
```

any idea as to why this is happening?
or perhaps maybe im doing something incorrectly.

Im using Selenium-Java "selenium-java-3.13.0"

JDK "10.0.2"

Chrome "Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

Comment: I experienced same issue and find out that I have to wait some time, wait until the value increases. It takes some miliseconds, but it does. In my case Thread.sleep(100); helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getWindowHandles()` method will return the set of window handles of the current WebDriver instance.

Here you are creating different instance of each url and trying to get the WindowHandles. So, it is returning the size as 1.

**Instance 1:**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**Instance 2:**

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.rediffmail.com/");
```

**Instance 3:**

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

you are finding the windowhandles after creating the instance 3. So, the `driver` object will hold the instance 3 and hence `driver.getWindowHandles();` is returning as 1 .

You can try by opening multiple different tab using the same driver object and then check the size of the WindowHandles.

For the understanding purpose, Please add the below steps after the instance 3 and you can observe the getWindowHandles size.

```
    //Latest driver instance is passed
    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String url1="https://www.rediffmail.com/";
    String url2="https://www.google.com/";

    js.executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])",url1); //New Tab will be opened
    js.executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])",url2); //New Tab will be opened

    Set<String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(ids.size());
    System.out.println(ids);
```

**Output:**

3

Comment: thanx a lot for the explanation. Now it makes sense as to why getWindowHandles was always returning one. Tried using JavascriptExecutor and now it works fine. Thanx. :)

Comment: @user9156301: Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick button and also give the upvote button by clicking on the up arrow button

Answer (score 0):

First of all we required to find how many windows are open for this required to store getWindowHandles in String as below and hope below code will helps.

Try below code

```
Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

int count = allWindowHandles.size();
System.out.println("Number of browser windows opened on the system is : "+ count);
for (String windowHandle : allWindowHandles) {
//switch to each browser window
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
String title = driver.getTitle();
//print the window handle id of each browser window
System.out.println("Window handle id of page -->"+ title +" --> is : "+windowHandle);

}
```